# Subsetting Data Table / Counting rows

Tags: r, data.table

When I count the rows in my data table by store code using the follwoing:

```
DailyProduct[, .N, by = ANA_Code]
```

I get 14 store codes with total rows of 120,237 - the same number of rows in DailyPRoduct which is great!

If I then get a unique list of the store codes:

```
unique(DailyProduct$ANA_Code)
```

I get 21 store codes which is more than I got above but is actually the correct number.

If I convert the store code from numeric to a factor, everything shows as expected, I get 21 stores and the row counts of each add up to 120,237

This is also causing me a problem when I aggregate the data, the sales value is correct but 7 of the store codes are missing.

Is there a fundamental difference in how data table treats numeric vs. factor when performing these operations?

I don't understand why this is happening so I can't provide an example as such so apologies for that.

Comment: Can you check if the 'ANA_Code' is a big numeric number.  If that is the case, load the `library(bit64)` before reading the data with `fread`

Comment: Could you add couple of store codes that are included in 14 and couple that are excluded?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but I use this in my script because R would convert this code to scientific notation:
    `options(width = 58, scipen=999, digits = 4)`

Included in the 14:
5000128300519
5000128680145
5000128022033
5000128300386
5000128680077
5000128888222
5000128020394
5000128211048
5000128689599
5000128689641
5000128210764
5000128689544
5000128689557
5000128781235

All the following were excluded from the count but included in the Unique command...
5000128680080
5000128689557
5000128689586
5000128689609
5000128689612
5000128689625
5000128689638

Comment: It is a big integer vector and this can create problems as I mentioned in the comment and answer.  Have you tried with `bit64`?

Comment: @akrun the data is extracted from Teradata via ODBC - does make a difference?

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek  You can check the `str(DailyProduct)` and see if it is Int64 class or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could happen if the 'ANA_Code' is a big integer and while reading it with `fread` incorrect output can happen.  One way would be to load the `bit64` library and then read it with `fread`

```
 library(bit64)
 library(data.table)
 DailyProduct  <- fread("yourfile.csv")
```

Comment: thought I would respond here to avoid confusion - str(DailyProduct) is showing as num

How 'big' can the number be before I run into problems? I can use a different code to identify the store but it will mean a lot of changes downstream which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek  That is the problem.  It cannot take big number

Comment: thanks for your help. I will just re-work my SQL and use a different store code.

Comment: would this also cause me an issue when I am merging 2 data tables using the long store code? I had issues yesterday when I used it in the 'by.x' condition which I've never had before.
So by.x = c("Store_Code", "Product") gave me spurious results but when I created a key of "Store_Code|Product" and used that it worked fine?

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek  If you can't convert it to `int64`, it can be converted to `character` class and use that as `by.x`

Comment: thanks again for the quick reply, really appreciate it. Changing class to character has worked!